# Detecting provider sign out with passport.js?

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth, openid, passport.js

I know that web apps don't normally tie their sessions to the sessions of their login providers, but I have a requirement in which I need to detect when the user signs out of their login provider so that I can sign them out from our application as well.

I currently have passport set up on my Node.js server. The login was very easy to implement and it's been working fine, but I haven't been able to find documentation on polling the current status of the user's session on the provider's end. Does passport provide a means to check this status? Calling the authenticate route again always does a redirect so I'm looking for a simple and ajax-friendly way to get a yes or no answer to the question: 'Does the user still have a valid session at their login provider's end? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to depend on the provider and the protocols they choose to implement.  What provider are you using?  What protocol is used to authenticate?

Currently, SAML is the only widely-used standard which defines facilities for federated session management.  Even in that case, I'm not sure how common those profiles are, since it is typically used for authentication only.

As far as Passport is concerned, that module is focused solely on authentication.  Session management and logout are separate (but related) concerns.  I'd like to develop other modules that work in conjunction with Passport; however, lack of deployed standards make it difficult.

Comment: I was trying out Google with OpenID. It seems that there's no clean way to get session status with OpenID, so I ended up going directly through Google+ API in order to achieve this. Wish I could've used Passport though, it is much simpler.